# Select record only if it contains same column value for all rows

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I have a table as below.

[image: Sample data.]

I only want `job_id` if it is rejected by all.

I tried using `group by` to count the result if it is not rejected by all.

So, I will check if at least one  record is as such which is still not rejected.

But it will give me the `jobs not rejected by all`.

I want `job_id` of those jobs which is `rejected by all`.

In the example above It should give record with `job_id =2`

```
  const jobRejectedByAll = await MatchedTechnician.findAll({
    where: {
      is_rejected: false,
      job_id: allMatchedJobs,
    },
    group: ['job_id'],
    having: sequelize.literal(`count(job_id) > 1`),
  });
```

Query:

```
SELECT job_id
     , 
  FROM matched_technicians AS MatchedTechnician
 WHERE MatchedTechnician.is_rejected = FALSE 
   AND MatchedTechnician.job_id IN (2, 3)
 GROUP 
    BY job_id
 HAVING COUNT(job_id) > 1;
```

Comment: See Nick's answer below for the correct way to ask this kind of question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `NOT EXISTS` query to check that no value of `is_rejected` is `false`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT job_id
FROM matched_technicians m1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                  FROM matched_technicians m2 
                  WHERE m2.job_id = m1.job_id 
                    AND (m2.is_rejected = false
                      OR m2.is_rejected IS NULL)
                  )
```

Output:

```
job_id
2
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gF4jKoHbnNvh2BytokWnkT/2)

An alternate queryway to do this is to count the number of rows for a given `job_id` and compare it with the number of `true` values; if they are the same, the job has been rejected:

```
SELECT job_id
FROM matched_technicians
GROUP BY job_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = SUM(is_rejected)
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gF4jKoHbnNvh2BytokWnkT/3)

*Update*

Sequelize version for second approach:

```
 const jobsRejectedByAllTechs = await MatchedTechnician.findAll({
    group: ['job_id'],
    having: Sequelize.literal('count(*) = SUM(is_rejected)'),
    attributes: ['job_id'],
  });
```

Comment: It is also filtering rows with  `NULL` values in the subquery. Also, giving duplicate rows which I fixed with `group by`. I think for `null` I have to `OR m2.is_rejected IS  NULL`.

Comment: @SujeetAgrahari your sample data doesn't show any `null` values, can you expand the sample data and explain what your desired result would be in that case? Note I added distinct to the original query to solve the duplication issue.

Comment: I added actual data. I tried toggeling the `is_rejected` state. It can differ from those in the image, but  will always be either `1 or 0` or `null`

Comment: So if a `job_id` has `null` values, should they be ignored, or treated as equivalent to `false`?

Comment: Ignored. If all the jobs are rejected `true`, only select the row.

Comment: Sorry, still confused. If a job_id has values of `true`, `true`, `null`, `true` should it be selected? or do *all* the values have to be `true`?

Comment: All the values have to be `true`. `false` and `null` should be ignored.

Comment: @SujeetAgrahari in that case adding `OR m2.is_rejected IS NULL` to the `WHERE` clause in the subquery should work.

Comment: Yes, `SELECT job_id
FROM matched_technicians m1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT *
FROM matched_technicians m2
WHERE m2.job_id = m1.job_id AND (m2.is_rejected = false OR    m2.is_rejected IS  NULL))
GROUP BY job_id;`

Comment: Do you have any idea how to achieve this in sequelize. I am using self association but been stuck.

Comment: @SujeetAgrahari I'm not a sequelize expert unfortunately. I've added another query and demo which might be easier to translate (it's quite similar to your original query).

Comment: I implemented the second one.

Comment: Just one more thing. If I do `!is_rejected` it will give me ` 1` if `is_rejected` is `0` and `0` if it is `1`. But what it will result in if `is_rejected` is `null`? I think it will be `null`, right?

Comment: @SujeetAgrahari Sorry about the lack of reply - it's been night time here. I see from your edit you got the second query working in sequelize - I'm glad to hear it.